# how much percent of executor memory is good to assign to 'spark.executor.pyspark.memory'?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How much percent of executor memory is good to assign to 'spark.executor.pyspark.memory'?
I am referring to: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties

Thanks!